# Why i'm getting exception ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

And how should i solve it ?
This is my button click method that i call it from inside onCreate:

```
public void addListenerOnButton()
{
    btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkipbutton);
    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        byte[] response = null;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                             response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);
                             if (response == null)
                             {
                                  text.setText("Connection Failed: " + generateRunnablePrinter(i));
                             }
                         }
                         catch (Exception e)
                         {
                              String err = e.toString();
                         }
                         if (response != null)
                         {
                             try
                             {
                                 final String a = new String(response, "UTF-8");
                                 text.post(new Runnable()
                                 {
                                     @Override
                                     public void run()
                                     {
                                         text.setText(a);
                                     }
                                 });
                                 iptouse = ipaddresses[i].substring(0, 26);
                                 connectedtoipsuccess = true;
                                 Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                             }
                             catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                             {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                 Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("encoding exception");
                             }
                             Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("test1");
                             break;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                         }
                     }
                }
           });
           t.start();
        }
    });
}
```

At this place in the method inside the FOR loop the variable 'i' should be final:

```
text.setText("Connection Failed: " + generateRunnablePrinter(i));
```

But since 'i' is also the variable of the FOR loop i can't make it final.
So i added the method : generateRunnablePrinter

```
private Runnable generateRunnablePrinter(final int value)
{
    return new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            text.setText("Connection Failed: " + ipaddresses[value]);
        }
    };
}
```

But now using this method I'm getting the exception:

ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the UI "text of the TextView" from another thread so you can try AsyncTask to do the work in the background in `doInBackground()` method then change the UI in the method `onPostExecute()`.
Check out the AsyncTask:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you're adjusting your UI, you'll need to run it from the UI thread. I'd recommend this function:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    // Your code here...
    }
});
```

If you're calling it from anywhere else but an Activity, you'll need to either pass down the activity or get the activity using getActivity() (i.e. from a fragment), and then call the function from the activity, i.e. `getActivity().runOnUiThread() { ... }`